# Parse a variant array using command line utils in bash

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, dbus

To get the current song being played in spotify (using [DBus](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html)), I use the following command:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player' string:'Metadata'
```

Now, the output of the command below is like: (stripped down for clarity)

```
variant       array [
     dict entry(
        string "xesam:artist"
        variant                array [
              string "The Black Keys"
           ]
     )

     dict entry(
        string "xesam:title"
        variant                string "Give Your Heart Away"
     )
     ]
```

The output is a bit long & I want to parse specific values from it like title, artist etc.

Googling said that [variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type) a popular datatype used in Component Object Model so I get there is a **better way** than using sed/awk to get the values. So, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Rather than trying to parse this yourself, it might make more sense to use a dbus client library, for example the `dbus` module in python.

Comment: I felt that it's an overkill to do it that way because I just want to know the current song being played.

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi It's almost never overkill to use a library that speaks the protocol which is being spoken to you, rather than using a text hack. If you do it wrong, it will break.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
awk '
  /string  *"xesam:artist/{
    while (1) {
      getline line
      if (line ~ /string "/){
        sub(/.*string "/, "artist:", line)
        sub(/".*$/, "", line)
        print line
        break
      }
    }
  }
  /string  *"xesam:title/{
    while (1) {
      getline line
      if (line ~ /string "/){
        sub(/.*string "/, "title:", line)
        sub(/".*$/, "", line)
        print line
        break
      }
    }
  }
'  variantArraySample.txt
```

Gives output

```
artist:The Black Keys
title:Give Your Heart Away
```

This assumes that there will always be at least 1 line difference between the input, i.e.

```
    string "xesam:title"
    variant                string "Give Your Heart Away"
```

That is to say, if your data is all rolled up into one line, then it will require further logic, so

```
    string "xesam:title" variant string "Give Your Heart Away"
```

(for example), would require changes to the above script.

Let me know if you need help formatting the output further for your need.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The following works regardless what order 'title' or 'artist' come in.  The only restriction is that after it sees `:title`, the next line containing `string` must be the title string; it doesn't matter how far away that line is though. Likewise for the artist

```
awk '
/:artist/{a=1;next}
/:title/{t=1;next}
a && /string/{
  sub(/^.*string /,"")
  artist=$0
  a=0; next
}
t && /string/{
  sub(/^.*string /,"")
  title=$0
  t=0;next
}
END{
  printf("artist:%s\n title:%s\n", artist,title)
}'
```

#### Output

```
artist:"The Black Keys"
 title:"Give Your Heart Away"
```